# Counter too large in R/exams cloze

Tags: r-exams

I am preparing a `cloze` question using `exams2pdf()` from R/exams, where the students are asked to fill in two 4 x 4 matrices. That makes too many (32) questions, and LaTeX complains about it `! LaTeX Error: Counter too large.`

I have tried to change the environment `answerlist` in the `*.tex` solution template using `arabic` instead of `alph` (default), i.e. from

```
\newenvironment{answerlist}{\renewcommand{\labelenumi}{(\alph{enumi})}\begin{enumerate}}{\end{enumerate}}
```

to

```
\newenvironment{answerlist}{\renewcommand{\labelenumi}{(\arabic{enumi})}\begin{enumerate}}{\end{enumerate}}
```

but I still get the same error.

UPDATED
I provide a MWE in `.Rnw` format

```
<<echo=FALSE, results=hide>>=
    
M1 <- matrix(rep(1, 16), ncol = 4)
M2 <- matrix(rep(2, 16), ncol = 4)
    
nsol <- 32
questions <- solutions <- explanations <- points <- type <- rep(list(""), nsol)
points[] <- rep(1, nsol)
explanations[] <- solutions[] <- c(pracma::Reshape(a = M1, n = 16, m = 1), pracma::Reshape(a = M2, n = 16, m = 1))
tol <- num_to_tol(unlist(solutions), reltol = 0.01, min = 0.01, digits = 2)
explanations[] <- solutions[] <- round(unlist(solutions), 2)
questions[] <-  rep("", nsol)
type[] <- rep("num", nsol)
@    
\begin{question}

\begin{enumerate}

\item Find matrix $M_1$

 \begin{tabular}{|cccc|}
 ~##ANSWER1##~ & ~##ANSWER5##~ & ~##ANSWER9##~ & ~##ANSWER13##~  \\
 ~##ANSWER2##~ & ~##ANSWER6##~ & ~##ANSWER10##~ & ~##ANSWER14##~  \\
 ~##ANSWER3##~ & ~##ANSWER7##~ & ~##ANSWER11##~ & ~##ANSWER15##~  \\
 ~##ANSWER4##~ & ~##ANSWER8##~ & ~##ANSWER12##~ & ~##ANSWER16##~  \\
\end{tabular}

\item and $M_2$     
    
\begin{tabular}{|cccc|}
~##ANSWER17##~ & ~##ANSWER21##~ & ~##ANSWER25##~ & ~##ANSWER29##~  \\
~##ANSWER18##~ & ~##ANSWER22##~ & ~##ANSWER26##~ & ~##ANSWER30##~  \\
~##ANSWER19##~ & ~##ANSWER23##~ & ~##ANSWER27##~ & ~##ANSWER31##~  \\
~##ANSWER20##~ & ~##ANSWER24##~ & ~##ANSWER28##~ & ~##ANSWER32##~  \\
\end{tabular}

\end{enumerate}
        
<<echo=FALSE, results=hide, results=tex>>=
answerlist(unlist(questions))
@ 
            
\end{question}
    
%% META-INFORMATION
%% \exname{Frustum}
%% \exsection{Tema 4/frustum}
%% \extitle{Tema 4. Frustum}
%% \exversion{0.2}
%% \extype{cloze}
%% \exclozetype{\Sexpr{paste(type, collapse = "|")}}
%% \expoints{\Sexpr{paste(points, collapse = "|")}}
%% \exsolution{\Sexpr{paste(solutions, collapse = "|")}}
%% \extol{\Sexpr{paste(tol, collapse = "|")}}
%% \exextra[numwidth,logical]{TRUE}
```

Comment: Could you please share an MWE?

Comment: Does my answer below solve your problem? If so, please accept the answer. If not, please refine the question and include a minimal reproducible example. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Moodle:**

If you are asking about two matrices, then I wouldn't use the standard itemized display but use a cloze with `##ANSWERi##` placeholders and then format the matrices as tables. A worked dummy example is included below and using `exams2moodle("matrices.Rmd")` works without error and leads to the following display in Moodle:

[image: screenshot of Moodle exercise with two 4-by-4 tables]

**PDF:**

Running `exams2pdf("matrices.Rmd")` also works without error. However, I'm not sure whether this is the display you want or how you would want to administer the PDF version of the exercise. Or is this just for your reference?

**Exercise code:**

The R/Markdown code for the `matrices.Rmd` file is provided below. For a similar table-based exercise see the [fourfold2](http://www.R-exams.org/templates/fourfold2/) exercise template on the R/exams web page. This also includes an R/LaTeX version of the exercise.

````
Question
========

Fill the following 4x4 matrix with the numbers 1 to 16 (by column):

|   |                1 |                2 |                3 |                4 |
|--:|-----------------:|-----------------:|-----------------:|-----------------:|
| 1 | \#\#ANSWER1\#\#  | \#\#ANSWER5\#\#  | \#\#ANSWER9\#\#  | \#\#ANSWER13\#\# |
| 2 | \#\#ANSWER2\#\#  | \#\#ANSWER6\#\#  | \#\#ANSWER10\#\# | \#\#ANSWER14\#\# |
| 3 | \#\#ANSWER3\#\#  | \#\#ANSWER7\#\#  | \#\#ANSWER11\#\# | \#\#ANSWER15\#\# |
| 4 | \#\#ANSWER4\#\#  | \#\#ANSWER8\#\#  | \#\#ANSWER12\#\# | \#\#ANSWER16\#\# |

Fill the following 4x4 matrix with the numbers 17 to 32 (by column):

|   |                1 |                2 |                3 |                4 |
|--:|-----------------:|-----------------:|-----------------:|-----------------:|
| 1 | \#\#ANSWER17\#\# | \#\#ANSWER21\#\# | \#\#ANSWER25\#\# | \#\#ANSWER29\#\# |
| 2 | \#\#ANSWER18\#\# | \#\#ANSWER22\#\# | \#\#ANSWER26\#\# | \#\#ANSWER30\#\# |
| 3 | \#\#ANSWER19\#\# | \#\#ANSWER23\#\# | \#\#ANSWER27\#\# | \#\#ANSWER31\#\# |
| 4 | \#\#ANSWER20\#\# | \#\#ANSWER24\#\# | \#\#ANSWER28\#\# | \#\#ANSWER32\#\# |

```{r questionlist, echo = FALSE, results = "asis"}
answerlist(rep("", 32), markup = "markdown")
```

Meta-information
================
exname: matrices
extype: cloze
exsolution: 1|2|3|4|5|6|7|8|9|10|11|12|13|14|15|16|17|18|19|20|21|22|23|24|25|26|27|28|29|30|31|32
exclozetype: num|num|num|num|num|num|num|num|num|num|num|num|num|num|num|num|num|num|num|num|num|num|num|num|num|num|num|num|num|num|num|num
exextra[numwidth,logical]: TRUE
````

Comment: Hi, apologies for the long time in replying, it has been a really busy time, and I really forgot about this and other questions. 

Thank you very much for your reply, but the problem with this is still there when I try to generate the pdf version of the exam, I get the following error message `! LaTeX Error: Counter too large.` 

No problem with the `.xml` version, and I’m not using the `.html` version. Any clue how could I fix the problem for the pdf version? I provide a MWE in `.Rnw` format. Once again, apologies for the delay.

Comment: The example is not self-contained, it is not clear where `Reshape()` comes from, please fix that. I have now replaced that line with simply `... <- c(M1, M2)` which is ok for this simple example, I presume.

Comment: In any case, I don't get the counter error with your example exercise. It works correctly in R/exams 2.4-0 (the current devel version on R-Forge). In version 2.3-6 it produces an error but this is not related to the counter issue you mentioned.

Comment: Sorry, Reshape is from the pracma library, I have added that to the MWE. I use R 4.1.0 with the 2.3.6 version of exams. I will upgrade my R distribution and check if the mistake is still there.

Comment: OK, thanks! The MWE now works for me and gives the correct output without any warnings if you use R/exams 2.4-0. You would need to format the `{tabular}` differently so that it becomes usable in PDF format though. Simply adding a grid with both vertical and horizontal lines should be sufficient for that. If your problem is resolved with this, please accept the answer, otherwise iterate the question once more. Thanks!

Comment: It all works fine now, thank you very much!!